# How to get rid of leading zeros in a number?

Tags: parameters, texinputs

I'm trying to check user input (a number parameter) for leading zeros and remove them. I wonder if such command is provided by `LaTeX2e`, or by one of the engines (`pdftex`, `xetex`).

Comment: `\number0000123 ` will print `123` (notice the trailing space).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### `\number`

See egreg's [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/502670/how-to-get-rid-of-leading-zeros-in-a-number#comment1269797_502670), for the simplest solution for integer numbers in the range -2147483647 to 2147483647:

```
\number000123⌴
\number-000456⌴
```

Result: 123 and -456

The space, marked with `⌴` ends the parsing of the number and prevents accident if digits are following in the normal text.

This solution is expandable and can be used inside `\csname`, `\label`, `\typeout`, for example.

### Package `bigintcalc`

This package provides an expandable method for removing leading zeros from integer numbers that are arbitrary large. From the documentation:

> `\bigintcalcNum {⟨x⟩}`
>
> Macro `\bigintcalcNum` converts its argument to a normalized integer
>   number without unnecessary leading zeros or signs. The result matches
>   the regular expression:
>
> ```
> 0|-?[1-9][0-9]*
> ```

Example:

```
\usepackage{bigintcalc}% plain TeX: \input bigintcalc.sty
...
\bigintcalcNum{000123456789123456789123456789}
\bigintcalcNum{-000123456789123456789123456789}
```

Result: 123456789123456789123456789 and -123456789123456789123456789

The macro is expandable, the package can be used with lots of TeX flavors (LaTeX, plain TeX, iniTeX, ...)

### Package `siunitx`

If the number is to be intended to be printed, package `siunitx` offers lots of options to format the number. By default, leading zeros are removed:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\num{000123}; \num{-000456}
\end{document}
```

Result: 123; -456